# Multiple Function Definition Error Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile, linker, wildcard, gnu-make

So this shouldn't be giving nearly as much trouble as it is, but I'm trying to create a more efficient makefile using wildcard operators as opposed to the tedious method I used to employ where you go through and make each individual object file and then link them together. But, for whatever reason, Whenever I try to run 'make' it gives me this:

```
multiple definition of 'ScreenMgr::ScreenMgr()'
/path/to/ScrenMgr.cpp:4: first defined here
```

then it also gives me another error immediately after this one that says:

```
undefined reference to main
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Though before these errors, my .o are produced and placed in the proper directory, so the error must be with the linker. I can include the c++ source if somebody thinks it'll help, but the files are practically empty as it is (Though I still put header guards in), because I just wanted to ensure that everything links properly first, so I can deal with problems like this without having to worry about the code as well. The directory structure looks like:

```
-MsSolver
|--src
|  |--main.cpp
|  |--ScreenMgr.cpp
|--include
|  |--ScreenMgr.h
|--build #empty directory
|  
|--Makefile
|:
|--bin
```

and here's the makefile:

```
CC:=g++
DEBUG:=-g
CFLAGS:=-Wall $(DEBUG)
LDFLAGS:=-Wall $(DEBUG)

SRCDIR:=$(PWD)/src
BUILDDIR:=$(PWD)/build
INCDIR:=$(PWD)/include
BINDIR:=$(PWD)/bin


FILES:=ScreenMgr main
INCLUDES:=-I$(INCDIR)
SRCS:=$(patsubst %,$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp,$(FILES))
OBJS:=$(patsubst %,$(BUILDDIR)/%.o,$(FILES))
LIBS:=-lX11
TARGET:=mssolver

#create executable and link
$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(LIBS) $(OBJS) -o $@

#Compile objs
$(BUILDIR)/%.o: $(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(BUILDDIR)/*.o $(BINDIR)/*.o $(INCDIR)/*.swp $(SRCDIR)/*.swp
```

Comment: Your problem is not your Makefile. Your problem is in ScreenMgr.cpp or ScreenMgr.h

Comment: You probably don't have a proper include guard in the header file.

Comment: Or maybe you're defining the constructor in both `.cpp` and `.h`.

Comment: Or maybe you're defining the default constructor twice in the .cpp file.

Comment: Actually the problem *is* with this Makefile. See the answer I haven't written yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(BUILDIR)/%.o: $(SRCS)
```

This line tells `make` that it can build *any* .o file from *all* of the source files.

```
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

And in this line, `$<` means the *first* dependency, i.e. the *first* source file in `$(SRCS)`, i.e. `src/ScreenMgr.cpp`.

So Make will essentially do this to build the object files:

```
$(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c src/ScreenMgr.cpp -o build/ScreenMgr.o
$(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c src/ScreenMgr.cpp -o build/main.o
$(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(LIBS) build/ScreenMgr.o build/main.o -o bin/mssolver
```

Based on the names of the .o files you might think it's working correctly... but it's not, it's actually linking two "copies" of ScreenMgr.cpp, and not linking main.cpp!

Change it to:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
```

instead.